# How can I replace the reportviewer's refresh button?

Tags: report-viewer2010

I have a requirement to hide the refresh button on the reportviewer toolbar and replace it's functionality with a standard text display button on an ASP.net web form.

I know how set the ShowRefreshButton property to false to hide the embedded button, but I can't figure out what code I need behind my new asp button.  I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
 With ReportViewer1
        .DataBind()
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters( _
    New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Year", ddlYear.SelectedValue, False))
```

It did the trick for me, setting the parameter or parameters seems to rebind the control.